# is Scanner in Java enough for reading input from a text file?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

### what i'm going to do

i'm going to build a phone book program in Java to do the following jobs:

1. read from two text files, *instruction.txt* and *phonebook.txt*
2. phonebook.txt includes some phone entry, each entry for a person
3. *instruction.txt* includes some instructions i would execute to *phonebook.txt*, such as add new entry, query an entry, delete an entry, etc.
4. for sure i would care about the output of my program, but for now, i focus on the input.

### my problem

i want to use ***Scanner*** to do all the input jobs, read in all the strings stored in instruction.txt and phonebook.txt, but i doubt if i can handle all the difficult conditions. Conditions like how to correctly get each entry, and identify what it is.

for each phone book entry, five fields are needed: *name*, *birthday*, *phone number*, *address*, *email*. And *name* and *birthday* are compulsory for each entry.

for instructions, they are *add*, *delete*, *save*, *read*, *query*.

### sample text files

here is a  sample of *instruction.txt*:

> add name Testing Three; birthday 13-05-1982; phone 12345677; address Address Three; email testing@gmail.com
> delete Testing One
> save

each entry is separated by one or more blank lines.
here is a sample of *phonebook.txt*:

> name Testing One
>
> birthday 13-05-1980
>
> phone 12345678
>
> address Address One
>
> email testing1@gmail.com
>
> -----------this is a blank line -------------------------
>
> name Testing Two
>
> birthday 13-05-1981
>
> phone 12345644
>
> address Address Two
>
> email testing2@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Scanner is sufficient to do the reading, though you'd need to use it the right way.

Getting the entries is simply a matter of calling a `Scanner.next...` method, and you can deal with the optional fields using `hasNext...`.

(Hint: use one scanner to split into lines, and then a new scanner to split each line.)